# CXF/JAX-B : No setter generated

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have following generated class from the xsd. I get following error when I try to post to the service. Reason being there is no generated setter, reason provided within comment in code section.  What is the work-around? I don't want to set it as ignorable, obviously.

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "token" (Class
>   com.rat.service.api.schema.ArrayOfToken), not marked as ignorable

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ArrayOfToken")
public class ArrayOfToken
implements Serializable
{

private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@XmlElement(name = "Token", required = true)
protected List<Token> token;

/**
 * Gets the value of the token property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the token property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getToken().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link Token }
 * 
 * 
 */
public List<Token> getToken() {
    if (token == null) {
        token = new ArrayList<Token>();
    }
    return this.token;
}
```

Comment: It may be because of the object you're posting: it may not match up with the generated classes, can you give an example of what you're posting to the service?

Comment: What is the input are sending?